# `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found, only sometimes

Tags: c++, g++, libstdc++

I get this errror

/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found

randomly when I launch my program. As a workaround, I can simply launch it again and it will work -usually- without problems.

Why do I have this error sometimes and sometimes I have not?

My main problem is that I would like to launch my program multiple times and I do that with a script that looks like:

```
for i...
do
./myProgram.o $i
done
```

and I always miss some entries because of this error.

myProgram.o is written in c++, if that could be of any help.

I have not admin access and I can not install anything, I am working via PuTTy on a ssh cluster.

Tell me if any other information is required

Answer (score 0):

> I get this error ... randomly when I launch my program.

This isn't supposed to happen.

The only explanation I can think of is that your program *sometimes* uses a different version of `libstdc++.so`, and that can happen if your `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` contains an NFS-mounted directory that is sometimes unavailable.

You can confirm or disprove this guess by running:

```
for i ...; do
  LD_DEBUG=files ./myProgram $i &> /tmp/my.$i.LOG
done
```

Then `grep libstdc++ /tmp/my.*.LOG` and see whether each run selects the same version of `libstdc++.so` or not.

P.S. I hope you didn't actually name your program `myProgram.o` -- that name conventionally should correspond to a relocatable object file, not a fully linked executable.